# Jquery Nailthumb Error after updating Yii2 Fx-asset Compose Plugin

Tags: jquery, yii2-advanced-app

I recently upgraded my `fx-assets` composer plugin and `Yii` version from `2.0.12` -> `2.0.13` and suddenly my thumbnails stopped working which are generated by the [`nailthumb`](http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php) plugin I am getting the following errors in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because `Yii 2.0.13`  includes jquery version > 3 and `nailthumb` does not support > 2, so you need to add jquery migrate before you are including the `nailthumb` plugin to support all such plugins for backward compatibility,